# change background of navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios4, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using this code to change the background of my UINavigationBar but it is not showing in the iPhone, but working fine in the iPhone simulator.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"Blue Bar.png"].CGImage;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
     [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Image Name"]]];
```

Comment: i have tried this but this method doesn't works on UInavigation bar

Comment: Than Check Your Image. It may be empty or Sometimes Not Supported. The above code is Definatly work for changing navigation bar background. I have sucessfully used this Code.

Answer (score 0):

check your image name may be in writing the name of image lowercase letters and upper case letters may validate.

Comment: may be you have committed mistake in written "Blue Bar.png" simulator accepts but device does not accept uppercase and lower case changes.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom class which sets the background.

```
@implementation MyNavigationBar

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation.png"] drawInRect:rect];    
}

@end
```

Comment: This NavigationBar should be a subclass of UINavigationBar?

Comment: Yes it is ... `@interface MyNavigationBar : UINavigationBar`

Comment: How to use this on self.navigationController.navigationBar ?

Comment: Create a MyNavigationBar instance and assign it to  `self.navigationController.navigationBar`